# Super capacitor causing overcurrent protection

Tags: power-supply, batteries, capacitor, supercapacitor, over-current

I'm making a power-supply circuit for some MCUs using a battery charging-discharging protect module MH-CD42 (both input and output is 5 V).

The module's datasheet says it has a 0.3 seconds switch time when connecting or disconnecting the DC power input, so I use a 10 F super capacitor to make sure those MCUs don't power off due to power loss. But when I power the circuit, it triggers the module's overcurrent protection (2.1 A).

I have tried to add a resistor between the module and the capacitor, but it still doesn't work.

Here are my circuits, with and without resistor.

[image: Without resistor]

[image: With resistor]

What should I add or how can I change my circuit to solve the problem?

Comment: Without knowing which exact module you are using, answers would be speculative at best. Please update the question with the exact module you are using.

Comment: @AdamLawrence Question updated.The module is called MH-CD42

Comment: How much voltage drop do you accept on the load side?

Comment: @Jens The loads are one ESP8266 Module and one Arduino Mega 2560 Rev3. I think 4.2 V is enough, so maybe less than 0.8 V, or I can add a DC to DC boost module to solve the votage drop.

Comment: If you can accept 0.8 V drop, you may charge the capacitor via 50-100 ohm and connect a Schottky diode parallel to the charge resistor in discharge direction. This way the capacitor charging current is much lower. During takeover the capacitor feeds the load via diode. A boost converter allows a smaller capacitor.

Comment: @Jens Do you mean change my circuit to this one [Citcuit 1](https://github.com/UnknownObject000/TemporyPictures/blob/main/circuit-01.png) or this one [Circuit 2](https://github.com/UnknownObject000/TemporyPictures/blob/main/circuit-02.png)?

Comment: I meant Circuit 2